# Py.test - Applying variables to decorators from a csv?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, pytest, testrail

Please bear with me while I try to explain my predicament, I'm still a Python novice and so my terminology may not be correct. Also I'm sorry for the inevitable long-windedness of this post, but I'll try to expalin in as much relevant detail as possible.

A quick rundown:

I'm currently developing a suite of Selenium tests for a set of websites that are essentially the same in functionality, using py.test

- Tests results are uploaded to TestRail, using the pytest plugin [pytest-testrail.](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-testrail/)
- Tests are tagged with the decorator @pytestrail.case(id) with a unique case ID

A typical test of mine looks like this:

```
@pytestrail.case('C100123')  # associates the function with the relevant TR case
@pytest.mark.usefixtures()
def test_login():
   # test code goes here
```

As I mentioned before, I'm aiming to create one set of code that handles a number of our websites with (virtually) identical functionality, so a hardcoded decorator in the example above won't work.

I tried a data driven approach with a csv and a list of the tests and their case IDs in TestRail.

Example:

```
website1.csv:
Case ID | Test name
C100123 | test_login


website2.csv:
Case ID | Test name
C222123 | test_login
```

The code I wrote would use the inspect module to find the name of the test running, find the relevant test ID and put that into a variable called test_id:

```
import csv
import inspect
class trp(object):
def __init__(self):
    pass


with open(testcsv) as f:  # testcsv could be website1.csv or website2.csv
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # skip header
    tests = [r for r in reader]


def gettestcase(self):
    self.current_test = inspect.stack()[3][3]
    for row in trp.tests:
        if self.current_test == row[2]:
            self.test_id = (row[0])
            print(self.test_id)
            return self.test_id, self.current_test


def gettestid(self):
    self.gettestcase()
```

The idea was that the decorator would change dynamically based on the csv that I was using at the time.

```
@pytestrail.case(test_id)  # now a variable
@pytest.mark.usefixtures()
def test_login():
   trp.gettestid()
   # test code goes here
```

So if I ran *test_login* for website1, the decorator would look like:

```
@pytestrail.case('C100123')
```

and if I ran *test_login* for website2 the decorator would be:

```
@pytestrail.case('C222123')
```

I felt mighty proud of coming up with this solution by myself and tried it out...it didn't work. While the code does work by itself, I would get an exception because test_id is undefined (I understand why - `gettestcase` is executed after the decorator, so of course it would crash.

The only other way I can handle this is to apply the csv and testIDs *before* any test code is executed. My question is - how would I know how to associate the tests with their test IDs? What would an elegant, minimal solution to this be?

Sorry for the long winded question. I'll be watching closely to answer any questions if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pytest` is very good at doing all kind of metaprogramming stuff for the tests. If I understand your question correctly, the code below will do the dynamic tests marking with `pytestrail.case` marker. In the project root dir, create a file named `conftest.py` and place this code in it:

```
import csv
from pytest_testrail.plugin import pytestrail


with open('website1.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    tests = [r for r in reader]


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    for item in items:
        for testid, testname in tests:
            if item.name == testname:
                item.add_marker(pytestrail.case(testid))
```

Now you don't need to mark the test with `@pytestrail.case()`at all - just write the rest of code and `pytest` will take care of the marking:

```
def test_login():
    assert True
```

When `pytest` starts, the code above will read `website1.csv` and store the test IDs and names just as you did in your code. Before the test run starts, `pytest_collection_modifyitems` hook will execute, analyzing the collected tests - if a test has the same name as in csv file, `pytest` will add the `pytestrail.case` marker with the test ID to it.

Comment: Nice! Just tried this out, this is the most immediate and simple solution for me. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason this isn't working as you would expect has to do with how python reads and executes files. When python starts executing it reads in the linked python file(s) and executes each line one-by-one, in turn. For things at the 'root' indention level (function/class definitions, decorators, variable assignments, etc) this means they get run exactly one time as they are loaded in, and never again. In your case, the python interpreter reads in the pytest-testrail decorator, then the pytest decorator, and finally the function definition, executing each one once, ever.

(Side note, this is why you should never use mutable objects as function argument defaults: [Common Gotchas](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/))

Given that you want to first deduce the current test name, then associate that with a test case ID, and finally use that ID with the decorator, I'm not sure that is possible with pytest-testrail's current functionality. At least, not possible without some esoteric and difficult to debug/maintain hack using descriptors or the like.

I think you realistically have one option: use a different TestRail client and update your pytest structure to use the new client. Two python clients I can recommend are [testrail-python](https://github.com/travispavek/testrail-python) and [TRAW (TestRail Api Wrapper)](https://github.com/levi-rs/traw)(*)

It will take more work on your part to create the fixtures for starting a run, updating results, and closing the run, but I think in the end you will have a more portable suite of tests and better results reporting.

(*) full disclosure: I am the creator/maintainer of TRAW, and also made significant contributions to testrail-python

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll definitely be looking at these links over the week!